# Why Django doesn't want to create startapp?

Tags: python, django

```
msinfo32@dEfaaPc2:~/Django/malybar$ python manage.py startapp testApp1
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
     ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

What i should to do?

Comment: is your virtualenv activated ?

Comment: rename your folder `Django`  in `~/Django/malybar` to something else and retry

Answer (score 0):

To begin using the virtual environment, it needs to be activated

```
source venv_path/bin/activate
```

this will help you

for more details [this](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/)  will help you

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to make a virtual environment first & activate it and then make your project and App in its enviroment.

Follow the Following Steps to go through a less error routine:

1. `Python -m venv newms`
2. `source newms/bin/activate`
3. `pip install django`
4. `django-admin startproject projectName`
5. `cd projectName` **Then** `python manage.py startapp appname`

Here you're basically creating virtual env named `newms` and activating it then install django and then you can go ahead and make your project and apps inside it.